# What are the performance difference using Axapta with a terminal server installation vs a client installation?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

This seems a 'stupid' question, but let me explain. I'm working for a company that use Axapta exclusively via Terminal server, so: 1 AOS server and 1 terminal server where all employee connect and use Axapta. 
I would like to know if there are some performance difference using the client installed in each single pc instead using the client in terminal server client. 
Thanks

Comment: this is way too vague - it depends entirely on how many users you have, term server spec, network spec, etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The installation of client software is the same.

Performance, well as all client instances runs on the same terminal server, one user can affect the performance of the other users.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is :

A. Working in Terminal Server is 
- you work at dumb terminal (your pc) and connect to Terminal Server. Workload happen in Terminal Server. Your pc is not overload by workload of Axapta client. It is need a lot bandwith transmit between Terminal Server and your pc, this bit transfered is remote desktop protocol (if you use rdp).

B. Working in your pc installed Axapta client is
- you work at your pc, which is installed Axapta client inside. So your pc will be like a horse load. It is much work inside your pc because data transmit between your Axapta client and AOS server. Your Axapta client performance will impact if there is mismatch code for running queries, for example run a report. Say your report queries in fetch method is on client side, and takes huge data to complete, no wonder your Axapta client will be blind for a while waiting the data come from server (AOS and DB).